# Is there a method in pyQuil to create logical boolean gates

Tags: programming, cirq, compiling, pyquil

is there another way to represent a boolean gate. The straight forward way would be to define a gate my a matrix and then apply this gate to the circuit. What i mean by that? For Example an AND-Gate is nothing Else then a CCX-Gate. So we want Qubit1 AND Qubit2 and store the result in Qubit3. Now instead of applying the AND gate on two qubits i want to apply it on multiply qubits. Now we could do it like mentioned above just defining the matrix for a Boolean Expression and then adding it to a cricuit but is there a different way to do it?

For Example Qiskit supports a feature which is exactly that. TKet does also support a similar feature the "ToffoliBox" where one could create Boolean Gates by defining permutations. And finally Cirq also supports something similar i guess, its called the BooleanHamiltonianGate (i never tried it).

So i wonder if pyquil support something like the other features.